# Tokenizing a string on literal slash

Tags: xml, string, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following code for a XSL `id` attribute setting for an anchor link:

```
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:variable name="articleUrl" select="concat(substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(document/documentinfo/uri/@path,$ps-group-path), 'content'),'psml'),'html')" as="xs:string*"/>
            <xsl:variable name="articleArr" select="tokenize($articleUrl,'//')" />
            <xsl:variable name="articleIndex" select="count($articleArr)" as="xs:integer" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$articleArr[$articleIndex]" as="xs:string" />
        </xsl:attribute>
```

The value of the `select` in the first `xsl:variable` in this case is `/news/2018/AT04651-article.html`. I want to split `articleUrl` by the literal slash `/`, and then do some other mumbo jumbo with the array to extract the last part of the array (`AT04651-article.html`), and then eventually lop off the `-article.html` part to access the value `AT04651`...

Only problem right now is that when I tried tokenizing the string by a slash, the value returned by the `id` value, I ended up getting the original string, `/news/2018/AT04651-article.html` not currently `AT04651-article.html`, and the value of `$articleIndex` comes back as 1... it's as though the `tokenize` function doesn't appear to work... Can anyone tell me where I've gone wrong?

I'm working with XSLT 2.0 in this instance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to split the string on a single literal slash, why are you tokenizing on a double slash? I think if you change that you will solve your problem.

I tested this hard-coding the input variable you supplied, then just outputting each item after tokenizing along with its index.

**Code**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <items>
            <xsl:variable name="articleUrl" select="'/news/2018/AT04651-article.html'" />
            <xsl:variable name="articleArr" select="tokenize($articleUrl,'/')" />
            <xsl:variable name="articleIndex" select="count($articleArr)"  />
            <xsl:for-each select="$articleArr">
                <item index="{position()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></item>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </items>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
   <item index="1"/>
   <item index="2">news</item>
   <item index="3">2018</item>
   <item index="4">AT04651-article.html</item>
</items>
```

Comment: Johnson, what kind of IDE did you use to test this?

Comment: Hi @Eliseod'Annunzio - I used Eclipse with 'XML Editors and Tools' installed, and a Saxon XSLT 2.0 parser configured (Saxon-HE-9.5.0.1.jar)

Comment: This has steered me towards the overall solution on my end, Johnson, thanks for that.